# Android AdView is behind view

Tags: android, admob, adview

I have a problem about Admob. Adview is behind of Buttons in my xml layout. But I want to see that Advertisement is over of Buttons or view.

How can i do this ?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaswK.png)

My layout is :

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-46102063xxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-461020638314xxxxxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_x="153dp"
    android:layout_y="262dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the button elements before the Adview:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    `enter code here`android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-46102063xxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-461020638314xxxxxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_x="153dp"
    android:layout_y="262dp" />
```